# How to prevent automatic focus on an input tag on Opera browser?

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I have an input tag on a webpage. Page should work on Opera Browser.

I have notice that as soon as the page load the input form is being focused automatically on Opera, in order to prevent this I am trying using onfocus="this.blur()", this works great on Chrome but not in Opera.

I need to keep not focus the input tag.

Do you have any idea how to make it works on Opera?

```
<input onfocus="this.blur()" id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Uživatelské jméno" data-href="username" class="focusable keyboard">
```

Comment: which Opera version? the latest one build on top of Chomium.

Comment: I would need it for Latest Opera Chomium and the version based on Presto.

Comment: On Opera 12.16 (Win 7), the `input` element is not focused initially. Please check that the problem really appears if you test with a page containing that tag alone, and specify the Opera version(s) in which the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually it is for a smart tv application, I have notice this Beauvoir on OPERA SDK for smart tv

Comment: Stupid question, but if it "works great" in Chrome, the user can never select this input. So it won't work normally as an input. Are you sure you need it to be an input? If so, couldn't you make it disabled or hidden?